# By event.target, how I know that it is checkbox or it is radio?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

**In my html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select">

<input type="radio" name="select">
```

name property same due to some logical reason

**in my JS**

I write below code:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').on("change",function(event){
    console.log(event.target.nodename);
    // on both cases it show "INPUT"
    }

    });
```

How I will know that I click on checkbox or radio button?

Comment: Instead of using JQuery you can (ES6+) also use [Element.matches()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) which returns a boolean.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`.nodeName` gives the `html` tag used so you have to use `.type` to get the type of the node there.

Try this one:

```
console.log(event.target.type);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AcZcL/)

Answer (score 79):

For those of you looking for the pure JavaScript way, it's `event.target.tagName`.

That property is an uppercase string of the element type, like "A", "UL", "LI", etc.

Comment: This will always be INPUT since both radio buttons and checkboxes use the INPUT tag. You want to check the type property which will be either "radio" or "checkbox"

Answer (score 10):

```
console.log($(event.target).is(':radio'));
console.log($(event.target).is('[type="radio"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `event.target.getAttribute('type')` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) like,

```
console.log($(this).attr('type'));// checkbox or radio
```

**Code**

```
$('input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]').on("change", function (event) {
    console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));// INPUT
    console.log($(this).attr('type'));// checkbox or radio
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the node type with jQuery you can use:

- $(event.target)**.attr('type')**
- event.target **.type**

> ```
> $("SELECTOR").click(function (event) {
> var idEventTarget = $(event.target).attr('id');
> console.log($(event.target).attr('type'));
> console.log(event.target.type);
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If the event passed to the progress or error event handler of an XMLHttpRequest, or an IDB success or error event handler, the target will be an XMLHttpRequest or (IDB Request?). There will be no getAttribute or nodeName property.

While there must be a better way, this will get the name of the event's target: targetname = Object.getPrototypeOf(ev.target).constructor.name.

For example, in the case of an http request, it returns "XMLHttpRequest".

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
event.target.checkBoxName.checked
```

where checkbox html like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxName">
```

It will return true or false.

> var isChecked = event.target.checkBoxName.checked;

Comment: I think the question was about checking if an event came from a checkbox or a radiobutton, but your answer is about checking if a checkbox is checked

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
function test(e)
{
   var eve = e || window.event;
   var ele = eve.target || eve.srcElement;

   switch(ele.getAttribute('type'))
   {
     case "radio" : //do whatever

     case "checkbox" : //do
   }

}
```